# CodeIgniter: 404 error on getting JS file

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am installing a project that is based on CodeIgniter. In the login page when I try to login it keeps redirecting me to login page without showing any messages. Looking at http access logs, I can see that the website can not find the js files:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Apr/2020:14:05:15 -0400] "GET /media/js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 487 "http://localhost/web/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:74.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/74.0"
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Apr/2020:14:05:15 -0400] "GET /media/login_script.js HTTP/1.1" 404 487 "http://localhost/web/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:74.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/74.0"
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Apr/2020:14:05:15 -0400] "GET /media/js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 487 "http://localhost/web/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:74.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/74.0"
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Apr/2020:14:05:15 -0400] "GET /media/login_script.js HTTP/1.1" 404 487 "http://localhost/web/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:74.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/74.0"
```

I searched about this error and some people suggested to change the .htaccess file. I changed it to the following but still have the same issue.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

Can anyone help me what is the problem? 
The project is located in `/var/www/html/web` and I am accessing it using `http://localhost/web/`

Comment: From the error message you can read a 404 code what means not found. Check your assets under.

Comment: It says 404 but I can access the js file directly for example accessing "http://localhost/web/media/js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js" loads the js file that mean the file is there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the `application/config/config.php` file and set your base URL properly.

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/web';
```

Answer (score 0):

since you can access the file directly, it means your *script src* path is wrong

check your path, change it with

```
<script src='<?php echo base_url()?>media/js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js'></script>`
<script src='<?php echo base_url()?>media/login_script.js'></script>`
```

dont forget to check your base_url setting in your config.php file