# stylesheet wont load because of mime type "text/html" not "text/css"

Tags: javascript, css, codeigniter, types, mime

I'm trying to access login form, however it won't load the css because of mime type. Does anyone know why?
--> here's my code
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNzLe.png)

Comment: This question lacks enough information to answer it.  Where are you seeing this error message?  in the Browser? in the server side logs?  Which css file is loading when this error happens?  Try using F12 developer tools in the browser to see what is loading and what is erroring.  This looks like it may be a php web page template.  Maybe tag with php if so.  What does the HTML look like after it is translated and served to the browser?

Comment: Yout code not show the input form

Comment: This may help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/61094222/12731030